Upgrading QGIS Plugin from local repository installs previous version
TL;DR: When upgrading a Plugin from a local repository QGIS says the plugin is upgraded, but downloads/installs the previous version, which is no longer accessible through the plugin repository.
My company maintains a local plugin repository where we upload internally developed and used plugins.
After publishing a new Version the I can correctly check for the new version through QGIS plugins -> Manage and install plugins… menu. The plugin is shown as There is a new version available and the option to upgrade plugin is available. When i check the webpage of the plugin repository and download the zip manually I can also see the new Version. So everything seems to work fine
However, when trying to upgrade to the new Version, even though QGIS prints get the message Plugin reinstalled successfully, somehow the previous version is downloaded. The version number for installed Version stays at the old Version, the message that a new version is available stays visible etc.
When checking the files in the Plugin-folder, they are changed when the upgrade was done but the content is the content of the previous version.
Reloading the plugin repository and restarting QGIS doesn't help. Installing the Plugin through manually downloading the zip or restarting the PC does help.
I tried to find out, if qgis has something like a plugin or download cache, but couldn't find anything. I also don't think that the problem is within the repository, as qgis recognizes the new version and it can be downloaded manually.
Can anyone help with this issue?

even i'm facing the same problem, exactly what you have explained. If anyone can help us would be very helpful.
Thank you:)

Found the solution: The data is saved somewhere here (windows): 
c:\Users\exampleuser\AppData\Local\QGIS\QGIS3\cache\
Apparently it is somewhere in the data8 folder, but I found clearing the whole cache more convenient. Either delete the folder through the explorer, through the QGIS Settings or via python. Found a description for the latter two here:
Clearing cache of QGIS 3.10 with Python
not sure, what other information are stored in the cache, so use at your own risk
